# IIS Web Deploy Task is Deploying Source Code to the Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-deployment, azure-pipelines

When using the Azure Pipelines the source files (.cs) are staged and deployed to the web server.  Any ideas how to prevent this?

Have tried using an exclude file but get a path not found error.

Expected behavior is the aspx files and contents of bin folder to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading the contents of your bin directory to your source control solution, which in turn is then being deployed?

I am using the Azure Git solution, and added a gitignore file to exclude the bin directory. When my code is built, the output (what will be the bin directory) will not contain .cs files

[image]